# Got App ID Uri was not configured error when using Azure AD connection

Tags: .net, authentication, auth0

I'm using Auth0 for authentication. While validating user with their credentials I am getting below error,

> App ID Uri was not configured

I have 2 clients, One client is using database connection, And I am able to validate user with that client. Second client is configured with Enterprise connection (Active directory/LDAP). It's not working and giving me error.

Below is my code,

```
var client = new AuthenticationApiClient(
    new Uri($"https://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:Domain"]}/"));

var result = await client.AuthenticateAsync(new AuthenticationRequest
{
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:ClientId"],
    Scope = "openid",
    //Connection = "Auth0AuthenticationDB",
    Connection = "fredsinc-waad",
    Username = vm.EmailAddress,
    Password = vm.Password
});

// Get user info from token
var user = await client.GetTokenInfoAsync(result.IdToken);
```

One more thing I notice is, If I use Lock login screen, Then it is working fine.

Do I need to change any setting in auth0 or I need to change my code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information available it seems you have configured a Microsoft Azure AD connection and did not specify a value for the *App ID Uri* field in the connection configuration.

As noted in the connection settings screen, this field is required if you want to use the `/oauth/ro` endpoint (aka authenticate with username and password like it seems to be the case).

The *App ID Uri* value to use should be available within the MS Azure configuration you performed. The following step-by-step includes references to that field so it might be useful:

https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory-native